# How can I save dynamically created Gravity Form fields into entries content?

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

The code below successfully creates a dynamic field and for a Gravity Form, and on submission the dynamic field data is included in the email content sent. However the dynamic field isn't saved in the "entries" data for that form submission, only the fields created manually using the plugin are. Anyone know how to include this data in the entries data saved?

```
add_filter('gform_pre_render_5', 'populate_wines');
add_filter('gform_pre_validation_5', 'populate_wines');

function populate_wines($form) {
    
    // create dynamic select field
    $props = array(
        'id'        => 51,
        'type'      => 'select',
        'label'     => 'Dynamic field label',
        'choices'   => array(
            array(
               'text'       => '',
               'value'      => '',
             ),
             array(
               'text'       => '1',
               'value'      => '1',
             ),
             array(
               'text'       => '2',
               'value'      => '2',
             ),
             array(
               'text'       => '3',
               'value'      => '3',
             ),
        )
    );
    $new_field = GF_Fields::create( $props );
    $form['fields'][] = $new_field;
    
    return $form;
}
```

Edit: Dave's solution below works great for the above function (thanks!!), but adding to the function to include the looped wine list (code below), it doesn't work, any ideas?

```
function populate_wines($form) {
    
    // options for select lists
    $select_choices = array(
            array(
               'text'       => '',
               'value'      => '',
             ),
             array(
               'text'       => '1',
               'value'      => '1',
             ),
             array(
               'text'       => '2',
               'value'      => '2',
             ),
             array(
               'text'       => '3',
               'value'      => '3',
             ),
        );
    
    
    // loop through wine list
    if( have_rows('wine_options') ):
        $wine_count = 50;
        while( have_rows('wine_options') ) : the_row();
            $wine_ID = get_sub_field('wine_option');
            $wine_name = get_the_title($wine_ID);
    
                // create wine select field
                $props = array(
                    'id'        => $wine_count,
                    'type'      => 'select',
                    'label'     => $wine_name,
                    'choices'   => $select_choices
                );
                $new_field = GF_Fields::create( $props );
                $form['fields'][] = $new_field;
    
            $wine_count++;
        endwhile;
    endif;
    
    if ( GFForms::get_page() !== 'form_editor' ) {
        return $form;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call the same function on the [gform_admin_pre_render](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_admin_pre_render/) filter. My recommendation would be to also add a check to exclude it from being output in the form editor but you may want that. If you don't, it'd look something like this:

```php
if ( GFForms::get_page() !== 'form_editor' ) {
    return $form;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, that works great! But now I've tried expanding the function to loop through the wine list (see above edits) and that's not working, any idea why? Cheers.